How to use the values of a 'pgfkey' with a list
How can I get access on a pgfkeys-list of the kind
\tikzset{MyCmdSettings/.cd,
colorlist/.code=#1
colorlist/.list={red, green, blue},% Default
}

I wrote a command \MyCmd where I want to call up the colors from the list, for example

Hint¹: Maybe it has to be made completely different, but I would like to have a key of the kind colorlist={<mycolor1>, <mycolor2>, <mycolor3>,....}
Hint²: At "Custom 2" I was not sure whether this is possible with a incomplete list.
Hint³: I would be better to work with pgfkeys (instead of xparse, xkeyval and so on).
MWE without desired result:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{MyCmdSettings/.cd,
colorlist/.code=#1
colorlist/.list={red, green, blue},% Default
}

\newcommand{\MyCmd}[1][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[]%
\tikzset{MyCmdSettings/.cd,#1}%
\def\pkv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/MyCmdSettings/##1}}%
%
\foreach \x in {1,2,3}{%% this foreach should stay as it is ======
\fill[] (\x,0) circle [radius=3mm];
}%%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Actually}
\MyCmd 

\section{Target}
\subsection{Default}
  \verb+\MyCmd+ 
  \MyCmd 

\subsection{Custom 1}
  \verb+\MyCmd[colorlist={black, gray, blue}]+
  \MyCmd[colorlist={black, gray, blue}]

\subsection{Custom 2}
\verb+\MyCmd[colorlist={purple, purple}]+
\MyCmd[colorlist={purple, purple}] 
\end{document}


If you leave the \foreach as it is, you cannot achieve the result you want without redefining some pgf innards. Technically, you could do this by, say, redefining \foreach or circle or whatever, but, in that case, just don't load the package and write your own from scratch.
The problem is that your definition of \MyCmd involves no connection between the \foreach loop and the list of colours. Nor does it include anything which might be used to forge such a connection.
\newcommand{\MyCmd}[1][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[]%
\tikzset{MyCmdSettings/.cd,#1}%
\def\pkv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/MyCmdSettings/##1}}%

I'm not sure what this is intended to do, but you don't use it and using it would obviously require changing the \foreach loop in some way or other.
\def\pkv#1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/MyCmdSettings/#1}}   
\pkv{colorlist}

If you try this code in the document, notice that it doesn't return anything. If we show the code stored in colorlist,
> \pgfkeysshower=\long macro:
#1\pgfeov ->#1 colorlist/.list.

but if you show the value, you get
> \pgfkeysshower=\relax.

because the key doesn't contain a value.
The .list handler doesn't set a default which happens to be a list. It rather causes the key to be executed in turn for each element in the list. So, in your setup, you've effectively done
colorlist=red,
colorlist=green,
colorlist=blue,

But the definition of colorlist doesn't actually do anything with the value - not even store it - so the effect is nothing at all.
\foreach \x in {1,2,3}{%% this foreach should stay as it is ======
\fill[] (\x,0) circle [radius=3mm];
}%%

Even if colorlist contained the values or the list, it wouldn't have any effect on the loop unless you alter the loop definition. If the key contained values, you could make one of the colours active, by just setting it as the default colour before running the loop. But there is no control tag inside the loop. Nothing within the loop uses any variable bar \x and only for position, not colour.
So I think you have to modify your constraints at least a bit. How best to modify them is tricky without knowing more about the purpose. I demonstrate two approaches. The first tries to alter the loop definition minimally. This has disadvantages and makes things awkward. The second is probably the more fruitful method to explore.
\newcounter{colourindex}

We're going to use a counter to name colours so we can use the loop iteration count for the colour of the fill. This involves only a very minor tweak to the loop's definition.
\tikzset{%
  MyCmdSettings/.cd,
  colorlist aux/.code={\stepcounter{colourindex}\colorlet{colour\thecolourindex}{#1}},

It's easiest to do this with an auxiliary key which steps the counter and assigns a predictable name to the colour.
  colorlist/.code={\pgfqkeys{/tikz/MyCmdSettings}{colorlist aux/.list={#1}}},

Now we define colorlist to execute our auxiliary key using the .list handler. So this will name the first colour colour1, the second colour2 and so on.
  colorlist={red,green,blue},% Default

Assign our default colours.
}

\newcommand{\MyCmd}[1][]{%
  \setcounter{colourindex}{0}%

We need to reset the counter each time because counters are global in LaTeX.
  \begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \tikzset{MyCmdSettings/.cd,#1}
    \foreach \x in {1,2,3}{%% this foreach should stay as it is ======
      \fill[colour\x] (\x,0) circle [radius=3mm];

Here we add colour\x to make the loop colour sensitive to the iteration count. Note that this will give an error if no third colour has ever been assigned, but it will fallback to the red,green,blue defaults as necessary.
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

This gives (what I think is) the target output and all together we have
\tikzset{%
  MyCmdSettings/.cd,
  colorlist aux/.code={\stepcounter{colourindex}\colorlet{colour\thecolourindex}{#1}},
  colorlist/.code={\pgfqkeys{/tikz/MyCmdSettings}{colorlist aux/.list={#1}}},
  colorlist={red,green,blue},% Default
}

\newcommand{\MyCmd}[1][]{%
  \setcounter{colourindex}{0}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \tikzset{MyCmdSettings/.cd,#1}
    \foreach \x in {1,2,3}{%% this foreach should stay as it is ======
      \fill[colour\x] (\x,0) circle [radius=3mm];
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

This is quite clunky and I don't recommend it unless you really have to do it this way. A more pgfkeys-type approach uses a simpler key setup, but makes the code for the command a bit more complex.
  /MyCmdA/colorlist/.initial={red,green,blue},

This assigns "red,green,blue" to /MyCmdA/colorlist and can be retrieved with \pgfkeysvalueof.
\newcommand{\MyCmdA}[1][]{%

No counter is required this time. Everything will be local.
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{/MyCmdA/.cd,#1}

We want to pass the value stored in /MyCmdA/colorlist to \foreach so the loop iterates over the list of colours. So we use expand list=true. For the position of the circle, we keep count of the iterations directly.
    \foreach \x [expand list=true,count=\i] in {\pgfkeysvalueof{/MyCmdA/colorlist}} {% 

Then \x is our fill colour and \i is our x coordinate.
      \fill[\x] (\i,0) circle [radius=3mm];
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

Again, this produces the target output, but it is also more flexible as it can be used with far longer lists of colours, if required, and avoids the (admittedly minimal) inconvenience of stepping and resetting a LaTeX counter.
\tikzset{%
  /MyCmdA/colorlist/.initial={red,green,blue},
}

\newcommand{\MyCmdA}[1][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{/MyCmdA/.cd,#1}
    \foreach \x [expand list=true,count=\i] in {\pgfkeysvalueof{/MyCmdA/colorlist}} {% 
      \fill[\x] (\i,0) circle [radius=3mm];
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}


Complete code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{colourindex}
\tikzset{%
  MyCmdSettings/.cd,
  colorlist aux/.code={\stepcounter{colourindex}\colorlet{colour\thecolourindex}{#1}},
  colorlist/.code={\pgfqkeys{/tikz/MyCmdSettings}{colorlist aux/.list={#1}}},
  colorlist={red,green,blue},% Default
  /MyCmdA/colorlist/.initial={red,green,blue},
}

\newcommand{\MyCmd}[1][]{%
  \setcounter{colourindex}{0}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \tikzset{MyCmdSettings/.cd,#1}
    \foreach \x in {1,2,3}{%% this foreach should stay as it is ======
      \fill[colour\x] (\x,0) circle [radius=3mm];
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\MyCmdA}[1][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{/MyCmdA/.cd,#1}
    \foreach \x [expand list=true,count=\i] in {\pgfkeysvalueof{/MyCmdA/colorlist}} {% 
      \fill[\x] (\i,0) circle [radius=3mm];
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Actually}
\MyCmd 

\section{Target}
\subsection{Default}
\verb+\MyCmd+ 
\MyCmd 

\subsection{Custom 1}
\verb+\MyCmd[colorlist={black,gray,blue}]+initial
\MyCmd[colorlist={black,gray,orange}]

\subsection{Custom 2}
\verb+\MyCmd[colorlist={purple,purple}]+
\MyCmd[colorlist={purple,purple}] 


\MyCmdA

\MyCmdA[colorlist={green,yellow}]

% xcolor manual: 35
\definecolorseries{xcolor g2}{hsb}{grad}[hsb]{.575,1,1}{.987,-.234,0}
\definecolorseries{xcolor s2}{hsb}{step}[hsb]{.575,1,1}{.11,-.05,0}
\resetcolorseries{xcolor g2}
\resetcolorseries{xcolor s2}

\MyCmdA[colorlist={xcolor s2!![0],xcolor s2!![1],xcolor s2!![2],xcolor s2!![3],%
  xcolor s2!![4],xcolor s2!![5],xcolor s2!![6],xcolor s2!![7],%
  xcolor s2!![8],xcolor s2!![9],xcolor s2!![10],xcolor s2!![11],%
  xcolor s2!![12],xcolor s2!![13],xcolor s2!![14],xcolor s2!![15]}]

\MyCmdA[colorlist={%
  xcolor g2!![0],xcolor g2!![1],xcolor g2!![2],xcolor g2!![3],%
  xcolor g2!![4],xcolor g2!![5],xcolor g2!![6],xcolor g2!![7],%
  xcolor g2!![8],xcolor g2!![9],xcolor g2!![10],xcolor g2!![11],%
  xcolor g2!![12],xcolor g2!![13],xcolor g2!![14],xcolor g2!![15]}]

\MyCmdA

\end{document}


[I should probably delete this answer, too.]

Why? Let me study first.

I'm still reading the explanations; But I've already skimmed the final code (it's largely self-explanatory), and that's exactly what I have in mind. Top!

OK, so here is my first study: You analyzed my code (which was clearly wrong) in detail. I already thought to myself: "It's something with a counter"; but I didn't know clearly how to do it - I wanted to keep the question as short as possible. However, the index-wise application of a list can be used for many applications; so please don't delete the answer. What you could do: divide it into two codes, something like "MWE-MyCmd" and "MWE-MyCmdA". I'm familiar with the topic and can handle it, but other users may find it a bit confusing. In any case: thank you very much!

Study²: If I limit myself to \MyCmd (without 'A'), I just don't know what \edef\tempa{#1} is for; If I comment this out, nothing changes in my opinion.

@cis Sorry. \tempa is one of those variables which seems to stick however many I delete. It's just left over from an earlier version which pre-expanded the list. Hopefully I've got them all now (?). I also included a complete code chunk for each method, which hopefully makes it a bit clearer. (Well, not complete complete, but complete method-wise.)

Please have a look here   https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/721429/46023
