Using of a pgfkeys-colorlist goes wrong
I used the solution
% written by @cfr --> https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/721338/46023
colorlist aux/.code={\stepcounter{colorindex}\colorlet{color\thecolorindex}{#1}},
colorlist/.code={\pgfqkeys{/tikz/SpiroSettings}{colorlist aux/.list={#1}}},
colorlist/.list={green!77!black, yellow, orange, blue, .......},% Default
%

from How to use the values of a 'pgfkey' with a list.
But in the \foreach-loop of my followong MWE it does not work.
What did I do wrong?

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=11mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.markings}

\usepackage{tkzexample}% for showing the code

% Spirograph ===========================
\newcounter{colorindex}% colorlist 1/3
\setcounter{colorindex}{-1}% for color0, color1, color2,...
%
\tikzset{SpiroSettings/.cd,
% colorlist 2/3 ====================
% written by @cfr --> https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/721338/46023
colorlist aux/.code={\stepcounter{colorindex}\colorlet{color\thecolorindex}{#1}},
colorlist/.code={\pgfqkeys{/tikz/SpiroSettings}{colorlist aux/.list={#1}}},
colorlist/.list={green!77!black,yellow,orange,blue,cyan,magenta,brown,black,pink},% Default
%
}

\def\n{28}
\newcommand{\Spiro}[1][]{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tikzpicture}[SpiroSettings/.cd,#1
]
\foreach[% foreach 2 %
evaluate={\A=int(mod(\B,\n)+1)},% \A: start, \B: end
evaluate={\C=int(mod(\B,4))}% repeating color number
] \B in {1,...,9}{%%

\draw[draw=color\C,
fill=color\C!44,
] decorate[decoration={
coil, aspect=0, 
segment length=6mm, amplitude=3mm,}
]{
(\A,0) -- (\B,0)
%% Test =======================
node[midway, font=\tiny, below]{color\C}% Colornumber
%% ==========================
};
}%%
\end{tikzpicture}
}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{tkzexample}[overhang, latex=99mm, code=yellow!30]
\Spiro  % Default
\end{tkzexample}

\begin{tkzexample}[overhang, latex=99mm, code=yellow!30]
\Spiro[colorlist={red,purple,purple}]
% nothing other
\end{tkzexample}
\end{document}


yes... no success...

You need to set the counter to zero in \Spiro. Or -1.

where is \foreach [ documented? i don't see it in the manual? i see \foreach \x [evaluate=...  with a variable \x ?

I updated my answer to use documented syntax in the case @DavidCarlisle pointed out and also for evaluate which uses evaluate=\i as \j using ... (page 1004).

@cfr Ulrike will be so proud of me for looking in the documentation

@DavidCarlisle ;) A policy of only reading docs you didn't write?

You need to reset the counter at the start of \Spiro. In the code I posted originally, I reset it to 0, but you will need -1 if that's your initial value.
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.markings}

% Spirograph ===========================
\newcounter{colorindex}% colorlist 1/3
\setcounter{colorindex}{-1}% for color0, color1, color2,...
%
\tikzset{SpiroSettings/.cd,
  % colorlist 2/3 ====================
  % written by @cfr --> https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/721338/46023
  colorlist aux/.code={\stepcounter{colorindex}\colorlet{color\thecolorindex}{#1}},
  colorlist/.code={\pgfqkeys{/tikz/SpiroSettings}{colorlist aux/.list={#1}}},
  colorlist={green!77!black,yellow,orange,blue,cyan,magenta,brown,black,pink,red,red,red, red,red},% Default
}

\def\n{28}
\newcommand{\Spiro}[1][]{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \setcounter{colorindex}{-1}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[SpiroSettings/.cd,#1]
    \foreach \B [% foreach 2 % note use of documented syntax
    evaluate=\B as \A using {int(mod(\B,\n)+1)},% \A: start, \B: end % note use of documented syntax
    evaluate=\B as \C using {int(mod(\B,4))}% repeating color number
    ] in {1,...,9}{%%
      \draw[draw=color\C,
      fill=color\C!44,
      ] decorate[decoration={
        coil, aspect=0, 
        segment length=6mm, amplitude=3mm,}
      ]{
        (\A,0) -- (\B,0) node[midway, font=\tiny, below]{color\C}% Colornumber
      };
    }%%
  \end{tikzpicture}
}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\Spiro  % Default

\Spiro[colorlist={red,purple,purple}]

\Spiro
\end{document}



Ahaaaa.... I checked it with your comment.... OK, it's clear. My fault. TYVM.

@cis Well, there was quite a lot of commentary in that answer, so easy to miss some detail. What is TYVM?

A shortcut for: 'T'hank  'Y'ou 'V'ery 'M'uch

@cis TYVM .....
